# Assign object to any widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Good afternoon.

Do you know if there is in Flutter something similar to the .NET Tag property or the Qt setProperty property? Basically I want to be able to assign an object, string... to any widget in Flutter.

Thank you very much.

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: Let's say that the database layer of the application, which is already implemented, has a mechanism to read and store the information coming from the interface.  For example, what I want is to tell a TextField something like "TableName|DataType|Value" so that the mechanism knows where and how to store the data.

Comment: I might not understand you entirely, but what's stopping you from having a wrapper widget to the `TextField` with extra properties containing this data?

Comment: It is an option but it would mean having to do it for each type of control (TextField, DropdownButton, TextFormField, Buttons, etc.).

Comment: You are right, but I'm not sure why it's bad. You don't have too many input types, and you can do it pretty quickly.

Comment: Could you give an example of what it would look like with a TextField for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that I like better. It is the Extension methods, a way to add functionalities to a library knowing nothing about its internal implementation. An example in my case:

```
extension myWidget on Widget {
    static Object _data = Object();

    Object get tag => _data;
    set tag(Object tag) {
    _data = tag;
    }
}

Widget setTag(Widget wdg, Object tag) {
  wdg.tag = tag;
  return wdg;
}
```

Usage:

```
Container(
          width: 500,
          child: setTag(
              TextField(
                obscureText: false,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Nº Historia Clínica',
                ),
              ),
              "###AUTOCAMPO###|HJ_07_RADIODIAGNOSTICO|HOJA_REFERENCIA|ENTEROTEXTO"
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example, as a followup to the comments:

```
enum DataType {
  text,
  number,
  date,
  time,
  dateTime,
  boolean,
}

class FieldData<T> {
  final String table;
  final DataType type;
  final T value;

  FieldData({
    required this.table,
    required this.type,
    required this.value,
  });
}

class SpecialTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpecialTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.table,
    required this.type,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.controller,
    this.decoration,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String table;
  final DataType type;
  final Function(FieldData) onChanged;

  // Here you declare TextField's properties you need
  // to use in your widget, and then pass them to TextField
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final InputDecoration? decoration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: decoration,
      onChanged: (value) => onChanged(
        FieldData(
          table: table,
          type: type,
          value: value,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And to use it, you can do:

```
SpecialTextField(
  table: 'users',
  type: DataType.text,
  onChanged: (data) {
    print('Table: ${data.table}');
    print('Type: ${data.type.name}');
    print('Value: ${data.value}');
  },
)
```